# How to manage GIT branches with different database credentials?

Tags: git

I have read some topics but perhaps my knowledge of Git is lacking certain aspects because I can't find any answers that would make my problem at least clearer or give my some ideas to solve it.

I have got a project that is a small Web App and currently I have the following branches:

```
- Master
  - Staging
  - Development
```

Staging and development are deployed in my server and have a specific set of credentials to point to their respective databases.

Master is supposed to be a branch that is ready to copy and deploy to other servers. I do not worry about deployments on the server because it doesn't support git, meaning I copy the files to the server via FTP. This is just about merging.

This is the simplest scenario:

1. I make some changes to **development** branch.
2. I create a **Pull Request** to merge with **staging** but of course the different credentials are also picked up as changes

How do I deal with the fact that I might have changes in database class I **need to merge** but I don't want to **overwrite** the credentials?

Should I keep it in a separate file and use `.gitingore`? Or `--assume-unchanged`? This is where I get confused as to how to keep it clean and simple.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't store credentials in git repo. If anyways you have stored it in git, then write build and deployment script also that will manipulate required string during build time.

Comment: In this case, if I put the credentials in a separate file, would using `.gitignore` be enough so that it never gets picked up by Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not put the credentials in Git!**

Also do not put in Git the settings that depend on the environment. Put in Git a sample configuration file that contain sensible defaults and explanation about how to produce the real configuration file and how to adjust it to match the environment.

1. Gather all the settings that are environment specific into a file, let's name it `config.ext` (replace `.ext` with the actual termination used by the language you use).
2. Add `config.ext` into `.gitignore` and make sure it is not already tracked in Git.

   - if it already is tracked in Git then run `git rm --cached config.ext` to untrack it;
   - make sure that the code does not work without `config.ext` and provides a meaningful message.
3. Make a copy of `config.ext`. Name it `config.ext.dist` or `config.ext.sample` and add it to the repository.
4. Make sure `config.ext.dist` does not contain sensitive information and is environment agnostic

   - replace any sensitive information (usernames, passwords, access keys etc.) in `config.ext.dist` with empty strings, asterisks or dummy values and make it clear in the documentation that the value needs to be replaced with a valid value;
   - use defaults that are suitable for the production environment for the other entries; or use defaults that are suitable for the development environment (to help the new developers start working on the project).
5. Document how to use `config.ext.dist` to produce `config.ext` (by making a copy)

   - extensively comment `config.ext.dist` and explain the meaning and possible values of each entry; if the format does not allow comments (JSON, f.e.) then describe it into a new page in the documentation.
6. Add the new and modified files described above to Git and commit.
7. Adjust the deployment scripts and procedures to use a previously prepared `config.ext` that is stored outside the Git repository. It should also remove `config.ext.dist`
8. That's all!

Comment: Thank you. That gives me much better understanding. What about .gitignore file? What if it needs to be different? Let's say I have folders in dev that I don't want to be tracked but once it's copied to a different (client's) server, then I of course want to keep those files tracked in their own repo

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your case. What contains the folder you don't want tracked on the development environment but you want it tracked on the production server? If it contains files uploaded by the users of the website or generated by the code of the website then they should stay in a separate repository. And you have to take care to not remove or replace them on deploy.

Comment: For example in staging I need to add some files related to front end so that we can test its functionalities

Comment: In this case in the staging environment you should deploy the code from a different branch. After the code is tested, the changes should be copied to the master branch (usually by merging the branch in `master` but it depends on the flow and procedures you use for development).

Comment: Thanks, I decided to tackle the credentials problem first and this definitely helped..I'll think of the other problems one by one : )